# KnownFolders.VideosLibrary picks all videos?

Tags: win-universal-app, directory, known-folders, video-library

in UWP "knownfolders.VideoLibrary", what exact folders does this pickup ? musiclibrary picks all music present on the hard drive, but VideosLibrary seems to pick only 2 folders on my harddrive which have videos. but there are other folders as well and they are not being picked. here is the code.

```
var files = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFilesAsync(
           Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the other folders into the Video Library.

Right Click a folder containing videos -> Include in library -> video.

You can prompt user to select a folder and add the folder to the video library like this:

```
StorageLibrary videoLibrary = await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId.Videos);
await videoLibrary.RequestAddFolderAsync();
```

Comment: ok i can do that but how will the user of the app will do it ? I want to access all the video files in their system without asking them, or they dont have to do anything and i just get all video files, isnt that possible ?

Comment: No, user has full control of what the app can access. You can't scan the whole file system without user's consent. You can user a [FolderPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207881) to prompt user for a folder, so you can search the contents inside that folder.

Comment: thanks man that really helped :) I found a way "RequestAddFolderAsync()" method for the folder picker to add them to library. thanks a lot :)